# Convertir los resultados de un api que incluye listas en un dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, script

tengo un api y la quiero consumir en R, pero viene en el siguiente formato:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y dentro del primer elemento también hay más listas, de este forma:}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les agradecería mucho si me pudieran apoyar en cómo sacar los registros en dataframes aunque sean varias de acuerdo a las distintas listas anidadas que existen.

respuesta del api en json (data)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No es tan simple, tienes una estructura anidada, podríamos transformar el primer nivel en un `data.frame` pero ¿que hacemos con las columnas que son otras listas? Pero antes siquiera empezar a mirar algo, necesitamos al menos un ejemplo verificable, en tu caso o la llamada a la API o al menos un ejemplo del objeto recibido, por ejemplo , la salida de `dput(a)`.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder, la respuesta del api la baje en un json el cual me arroja el siguente DF (data) pero como se observa en la última imagen, esta compuesta por otros DB dentro de las columnas, quisiera saber como pued extraer esos DF por ejemplo bienes_servicios  y que la llave sea un ID que esta dentro del DF data